# xindy with texmaker and miktex on ubuntu yield: call to xindy failed error code 255

Tags: miktex, texmaker, ubuntu, xindy

I am trying to use the [latex template of my university](https://github.com/SCD-Aix-Marseille-Universite/latexamu) and already just compiling the template does not go through because of xindy.

Texmaker tells me:

```
***Call to xindy failed*** Check 'these.alg' for details
```

The these.alg contain the following:

```
*** Unable to execute: '"xindy"  -L french -C utf8 -I xindy -M "these" -t "these.alg" -o "these.acr" "these.acn"' ***

Failed with error code 255.

Status report:

xindy.pl: not a symlink as required for TeX Live at <my home>/.miktex/texmfs/install/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl line 418.

xindy didn't create a transcript.
Check that xindy has been installed and
is on your system's PATH.
Your PATH environment variable is set to: 
<content of my PATH>
Try manually running:
"xindy"  -L french -C utf8 -I xindy -M "these" -t "these.alg" -o "these.acr" "these.acn"
```

(the things between <> are replaced to avoid giving system details)

Xindy is installed according to MiKTeX. Because this is linux and seems trivial the first thing we tried was to create a symlink pointing to the original xindy.pl. The error message changed, now it is looking for a xindy.mem that is not found. Indeed, this file is nowhere to be found in the miktex installation of xindy.

I would like to point out that this exact setup (the template compiled by texMaker using MiKTeX as a package manager) works flawlessly in windows10 and 7 but I do not have another ubuntu distribution at hand to compare.

Has anyone seen something similar? What could be the cause for this error and how could it be fixed?

Should you want to try it yourself: [download the template from github](https://github.com/SCD-Aix-Marseille-Universite/latexamu) and then you need to make some custom configuration following the instructions [here](https://github.com/SCD-Aix-Marseille-Universite/latexamu/pull/28/commits/550d6c162ee494d982854d7ef5042d83546d7cc8)

Best regards,
alchifon

Other usefull informations:
MiKTeX and TeXMaker are in their latest version, perl is installed by default in ubuntu (needed for xindy).

Runing xindy as suggested in the last line of the these.alg leads to a similar error message:

```
xindy.pl: not a symlink as required for TeX Live at <myhome>/.miktex/texmfs/install/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl line 418.
```

I could not find anyone that has a problem with this in ubuntu and the most recent post regarding xindy mostly date back to 2015.

Comment: better use texlive on linux if you want to use xindy. The perl script is rather old and assumes that miktex runs on windows only.

Comment: After giving a go at texlive it works once old legacy linux libraries have been downloaded. Now I have a problem with your comment because texlive also uses a perl script named the same way and can also be ran on windows. So why does miktex ,who can also be used on either platform, not manage to do the same thing? (sorry I very much like miktex because a lot more user friendly)

Comment: the problem is not with miktex but with xindy.pl. Look into the script (it should be in scripts/xindy). Starting with line 392 it tries to setup search pathes and similar for the various tex systems. The script was written for texlive and some years ago some effort was made to get it working on miktex too but at that time miktex was only on windows. You would have to find someone to extend. Beside this: I have both miktex and texlive and imho there is not much difference regarding user friendliness.

Comment: Confirmed issue still occurring in 2021 with MiKTeX